# Oracle sql queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a small relational database for school and having trouble with a simple query. I am supposed to find all records in a table that have a field with the word 'OMG' somewhere in the text. 
I have tried a few other and I can't figure it out. I am getting an invalid relational operator error.

my attempts:

```
select * from comments where contains('omg');
select * from comments where text contains('omg');
select * from comments where about('omg');
```

and several more variations of the above. As you can see I am brand spanking new to SQL.
text is the name of the field in the comments table.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: CONTAINS is a special keyword used with CONTEXT indexes - see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the column name is `text`:

```
select * from comments where text like '%omg%';
```

The percentage `%` is a wild-card which means that any text can come before/after `omg`

Pay attention, if you don't want the results to contain words in which omg` is a substring - you might want to consider adding whitespaces:

```
select * from comments where text like '% omg %';
```

Of course that it doesn't cover cases like:

- omg is at the end of the sentence (followed by a ".")
- omg has "!" right afterwards
- etc

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [`LIKE` operator](http://psoug.org/definition/LIKE.htm) with wildcards (%):

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE text LIKE '%omg%';
```

Comment: ans this answer is different than mine cause ?

Comment: Nope, not much different. We just hit it around the same time -- no harm no foul. Yours has a description of what a wildcard does. Mine has a link to `LIKE` documentation, so I'll leave it for reference.